# I2C clock stretching details

Tags: i2c

I am new to I2C, and after reading about clock streching I become puzzled about mechanism it works. About clock stretchig I've read that slave is allowed to hold down the clock if it needs to reduce the bus speed, but haven't understand how can slave phisically keep SCL low?

Comment: As this question is about the electronic aspect of I2C, it should be on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Agreed this belongs in the EE stackexchange but briefly: I2C uses only "open collector" outputs which only drive the line low and, instead of driving high, become high-Z (effectively no connection) and allow a pull-up resistor to pull the line high. This allows anything on the bus to drive the clock (or data) line low.